# How to run C# 4.0 app on Linux OS using mono?

Tags: linux, c#-4.0, mono

I want to run my c# application with OS Linux using Mono. I am new to this cross platform migration? Please tell the procedure for doing that?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It very much depends on what type of application it is. For a console or WinForms app, it may be simple. [Mono doesn't support WPF](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF).

Well, the first think you'll need to do is install Mono of course. Then you probably want to run [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to determine your application's compatibility. There's a whole separate page about [porting WinForms apps](http://mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications).

If all is well, you should just be able to run your application using:

```
mono MyApplication.exe
```

after copying the binaries over.

If your application is actually a web service or web application, you'll want to think about the various hosting options.

I suspect you'll want to read a lot of the pages on the [Mono Start Page](http://mono-project.com/Start).

Comment: Adeel: I am using C#4.0 client server windows Desktop application and also SOAP web services.How do you feel mono compatibility about my application that u thinking? Please give your thoughts...

Comment: @Saravanan: I don't know how compatible Mono is with that, but MoMA should be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your application is 100% compatible with Mono Framework using [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).
Remove or replace those unimplemented parts with Mono's implementation or third party libraries that works with Mono. Or if you think it should work fine, just execute it with Mono Framework 2.8 or higher. Better go with 2.10 which is default's profile is on 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IDE, [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) that supports Web and Desktop applications. Open the project files (monodevelop supports visual studio project files) from monodevelop, compile and run.

you can browse mono website [here](http://mono-project.com), where you can find which features are supported and which are not supported and why.

Comment: yes it is, actually i was assuming that the project has only source code and there might be some modifications, although if you have exe, you can directly execute exe by using `mono` command.